# Rename [ionicpopup] to [ionic-popup]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

This is a proposal to rename  [ionicpopup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionicpopup) to [ionic-popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-popup), for homogeneity with [ionic-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework), [ionic-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-view), [ionic-popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-popover), etc.